# How to get hierarchy data in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have Entity as below

```
public class user
{
   int userid
   string name
   int? ManagerId
}

public class TaskList
{
   int taskid
   string taskname
   int assignto//Foraign key userid
}
```

I want to write a Linq extension to get all task under a particular manager which includes task of employees under that manager as well.

Comment: You're using Entity Framework??

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Just add a property virtual to create the relationship on the object class.

```
public class User 
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ManagerId { get; set; }
}

public class TaskList 
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
    //ForeignKey
    public int AssignTo { get; set; }
    //Virtual property
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```